# CSS Drop Down Navigation Fade-In

Tags: css, navigationbar

I am creating a website and I have this drop down CSS code created and working.  I understand the tags could be a lot better, but I have very, very limited access to the website's HTML and CSS code, so I have to work with what I have.  Anyway, the code itself and the drop down menu works, but I am having a lot of trouble adding some kind of effect to this.  I would like a really cool 3D design if at all possible, but I will absolutely take a simple fade-in drop down animation.  Thanks for any help you can give me!

```
    `/* NAVIGATION HOVER MENUS*/

    #navigation ul.menu li {
        float: left;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #navigation .menu li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #navigation #main-menu a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 25px;
    }

    #main-menu a.active, #main-menu a:hover, #main-menu a.active-trail {}

    #navigation ul li a.active, #navigation ul li.active-trail a {
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    #navigation #main-menu li.active, #navigation #main-menu li:hover, #navigation #main-menu li.active-trail {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    #navigation #main-menu li.active > a, #navigation #main-menu li:hover > a, #navigation #main-menu li.active-trail > a {
        box-shadow: none;
        background: #fff;
    }

    .front #navigation #main-menu li:first-child {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .front #navigation #main-menu li:first-child a {
    }

    #navigation ul.menu li .menu li {
        float: none;
    }

    #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li, #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li:hover, #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li.active-trail {
    border-top: none;
    display: block;
    }


     #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li a {
        padding: 10px 25px;
        display: block;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        top: 0;
        color: #666;
    }

     #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li.last a {
          background: #fff;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
          -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
          -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
     }


     #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li a:hover, #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li a.active-trail {
         color: #f89433;
     }

    #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li.menu__item.is-leaf {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #navigation .menu li .menu {
        position: relative;
        display: inherit;
    }

    #navigation .menu li .menu {
      display: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        min-width: 200px;
        display: none;
    }


    #navigation .menu li .menu li:hover a {
        color: #eb9246;
    }

    #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li  .menu li {
        display: none;
    }

    #navigation .region-sidebar-first .menu li .menu li .menu li {
        display: block;
    }


     #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

     #navigation #main-menu .menu li > .menu li {

    }

     #navigation #main-menu .menu li .menu li:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    #navigation .menu li:hover .menu {
      display: block !important;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
```

Comment: What is the current programming issue you have? "I'd like something cool" is a bit broad!

Comment: Sorry about that, the issue I have is that, while the drop down menu does work, it basically just brings up the drop down menu when you hover over it.  There is no fade or any kind of transition/animation to make it look smooth.  It still looks fine, but I would love it if I could have some kind of animation implemented into the drop down bar.

Comment: Can you include html structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example, I tried working with your `css` but you didn't include `html` and the `css` itself is frankly a little messy.

The real magic happens with these few lines:

```
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
```

If you define opacity of 0 for a hidden dropdown and then give it opacity of 1 on hover, those 4 lines will render a smooth animation. I set the timing to 2 seconds to exaggerate. You'd want it to be more like 0.5 seconds or less.

`all` means that ALL the differences in css between `normal` and `hover` will be animated.

https://jsfiddle.net/f2hno7do/2/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  The divs and classes that were define were incredibly confusing, but once I figured out which was which I was able to create a nice animation.  I could not post the html because i do not have full access to it, and the CSS is somewhat restricted by my company.  Thanks for all your input!